# Multi Line editable cell in tableview javafx

Tags: java, javafx-2, tableview, cell

Hi I just want multi line cell in JavaFX which is editable.

```
@FXML
private TableColumn bookName;

  @Override
  public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        tableView.setEditable(true);
        //      setCellFactory();   
        bookName.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn()); // If I comment this line and uncomment above line then cell will be multiline but not editable
        bookName.setOnEditCommit(
                new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Books, String>>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Books, String> t) {


                if (t.getNewValue().equals("") || t.getNewValue().length() < 3) {
                    info.setText("Book name must be greater than 3 characters.");
                    ((Books) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                            t.getTablePosition().getRow())).setBookName(t.getOldValue());
                    return;

                }

                ((Books) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                        t.getTablePosition().getRow())).setBookName(t.getNewValue());
            }
        });

    }
```

If I set custom cellFactory, cell will be multiline but not editable

```
private void setCellFactory() {

        Callback<TableColumn, TableCell> cellFactory = new Callback<TableColumn, TableCell>() {
            @Override
            public TableCell call(TableColumn param) {
                final TableCell cell = new TableCell() {
                    private Text text;

                    @Override
                    public void updateItem(Object item, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);
                        if (!isEmpty()) {
                            text = new Text(item.toString());
                            text.setWrappingWidth(140);
                            setGraphic(text);
                        }
                    }
                };
                return cell;
            }
        };

        bookName.setCellFactory(cellFactory);
    }
```

Not editable multiline cell.
[image]

Comment: See the "Example 12-11 Alternative Solution Of Cell Editing" of [Oracle's tableview tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/table-view.htm). In there you can tryto use textarea instead of textfield.