# Editable multiline cell in TableView

Tags: javafx, tableview, javafx-8

(There [already is a question regarding this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21773383/multi-line-editable-cell-in-tableview-javafx) but it has no answer and the comment isn't helpful either.)

I've got a TableView and I'd like to have a column with multiline labels that I can edit. Ideally, the behaviour would be like a `TextFieldTableCell` but with multiline support:

- It displays text like a label.
- When clicked, it transforms into a `TextField` (or in this case, a `TextArea`) so the text can be edited.

I haven't found a solution for this yet. The only workaround I've got right now is put a `TextArea` as the cell's "graphic":

```
    descriptionTableColumn.setCellFactory(param -> new TableCell<Attachment, String>() {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            if (empty) {
                setGraphic(null);
            } else {
                TextArea area = new TextArea(item);
                area.setMinHeight(USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);
                area.setPrefHeight(USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);
                area.setMaxHeight(USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);
                setGraphic(area);
            }
        }
    });
```

(Code to listen to the text changes is missing here; it doesn't trigger the `OnEditCommit` event.)

However, the `TextArea` is always rendered as a normal `TextArea` with a border and white background. I can live with that. But the area also always renders with a certain height (about 180px) even when it's empty, even though I set `USE_COMPUTED_SIZE`.

So the question is:

- Is there a way to get the ideal behaviour, similar to the `TextFieldTableCell`?
- If not, is there a way to have the `TextArea` only use as much height as needed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, the basic idea is to copy the `TextFieldTableColumn` and adjust its behavior to create a `TextAreaTableColumn`. I hacked a small working example implementation together: https://gist.github.com/eckig/30abf0d7d51b7756c2e7

Usage:

```
TableColumn<?, ?> column = new TableColumn<>();
column.setCellValueFactory(...);
column.setCellFactory(TextAreaTableCell.forTableColumn()); // add StringConverter if neccessary
tableView.getColumns().add(column);
```

But, there are still some things left which need to be implemented / some tuning:

1. Adjust [prefRowCount](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextArea.html#prefRowCountProperty) to show only the necessary amount of rows.
2. Maybe adjust [prefColumnCount](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextArea.html#prefColumnCountProperty)?
3. Because the "Enter" Key gets consumed for a new-line, I had to add a Save Button to commit the edit. This is somewhat ugly, but for now I do not have a better idea.

But hopefully you get the idea ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your effort, that helped quite a bit. I changed the code to commit on focus loss but then noticed there are problems with text that is too long and should wrap… which seems to be another unsolved problem in JavaFX's table view. Since I already lost too many hours with this and now even more problems appeared I'm redesigning my UI to avoid this scenario. Unless someone comes up with an interesting idea I'll accept your answer on Monday.

Comment: I updated the linked code example: I removed the save button, commit is now done by Shift+Enter. On focus lost is not a good idea, so I discarded it. Additionally I found a solution for the row count property. It is not working 100% perfect, but it is a good start for now.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/TurekBot/69495ba2b15771c8118f4be1ec722381

Here is updated gist link.